# Detect plugged & unplugged event on headphone jack with native iOS 7 SDK

Tags: ios

I'm trying to find a way to detect the plugged/unplugged event on headphone Jack in Native iOS SDK, specifically on latest version (iOS 7).Is there a way to do it in this version?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an event for when the headphones are unplugged?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452441/is-there-an-event-for-when-the-headphones-are-unplugged)

Comment: Tutorial : http://www.makebetterthings.com/iphone/headphone-plug-in-plug-out-event-in-ios/

Comment: @0xced - The links provided in that page are broken. :(

Comment: I just fixed the link.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(routeChanged:) name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification object:nil];


- (void)routeChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSNumber *reason = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey];

    if ([reason unsignedIntegerValue] == AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonNewDeviceAvailable) {

    } else if ([reason unsignedIntegerValue] == AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonOldDeviceUnavailable) {

    }
}
```