# iOS play/pause video playing on other device by bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, mediacontroller

I want build a iOS app have some function:

- Connect to another iphone (Target phone) by bluetooth connection (I did it  completely)
- Have two button: play, pause. After connect to Target phone, user can switch state play or pause of video playing on target phone (like video playing on youtube, netflix, hulu).
- I tested with: MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer.pause() but it only work with system music app, I need work with youtube, netflix...

Anyone have some idea? Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452441/is-there-an-event-for-when-the-headphones-are-unplugged

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please, provide minimal and relevant example of the code you've tried so far.

Comment: thank you, but not relate to my problem